# How to wrap redux store to my App.js in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './Home.js';
import EntryPoint  from './src/containers/EntryPoint.js';
import Stage2 from './src/containers/Stage2.js';


const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'Material Management',
        },
    },
     EntryPoint: {
         screen: EntryPoint,
         navigationOptions: {
             headerTitle: 'Entry Point'
         }
     },
    Stage2 : {
        screen : Stage2,
        navigationOptions : {
            headerTitle : 'Stage 2'
        }
    }
});

export default RootNavigator;
```

The above code is my App.js 
I want to wrap the redux store around it. How do i do that . Couldn't find a proper documentation for redux setup with React-native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { createStore,bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect, Provider  } from 'react-redux'
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}
let Container = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RootNavigator);

export default class APP extends Component{
    render(){
        return (<Provider store={store}>
                     <Container/>
            </Provider>)
    }
};
```

Comment: so this becomes my Entry file ?

Comment: @YashSharma yes, RootNavigator is actually a common component. i assume you have no problem with how to warp a component with Redux