# how to wrap stack navigator component inside redux store in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to wrap my stack navigator component into a redux store with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334568/how-to-wrap-redux-store-to-my-app-js-in-react-native).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WelcomePage from './components/welcomePage';
import Register from './components/register';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Provider,connect } from 'react-redux';
import  store  from './store/store';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';   

function mapStateToProps=state => {
    return state;
}
function mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

const handleSubmit=values=> {
  console.log(values);
}
const Navigationapp=StackNavigator({welcome:{screen:WelcomePage},register:{screen:props=><Register {...props} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />}});
const Container = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Navigationapp);
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (<Provider store={store}>
                     <Container/>
            </Provider>)
    }
};
```

**register.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Field,reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Text,Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import { View,Button } from 'react-native';

const renderField=({label,keyboardType,name}) => {
    return(
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',height:50,alignItems:'center' }}>
                <Text>
                    <h4>{label}</h4>
                </Text>
                <Input />
            </View>
    )
}
const RegisterForm=props => {
    const {handleSubmit}=props;
    return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',margin:40,justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>

                <Field label="Username" component={renderField} name="username" />
                <Button title='SUBMIT' onPress={handleSubmit} />

            </View>
    )
}
const Register=reduxForm({
    form:'register',
})(RegisterForm);
export default Register;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore,combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
const rootReducer=combineReducers({
    form:formReducer
})
const store=createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;
```

I am using redux form in my register component and trying to store the values into the redux-store.
when I click on the register link it shows following error
[image]

What the issue is here?

Comment: No Action for mapDispatchToProps. Try simply with following just to make your application up:
 function mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch) => {
    return { }
}

Comment: i am edited the question with my new error.please check it.

Comment: Try with this:
1. First import  import { createStore } from 'redux';
2. Add this line : const store = createStore();

Comment: solved by removing the braces around the store.because I am using export default for exporting the store.

Comment: can you help me to solve my code for creating a redux form in react-native?

Comment: You can use react-redux-form and its LocalForm. It doesnt need to have form data in the redux state and probably not in the react state as well

Comment: @rohankangale I am edited the question with my register component and new error.please check it.

Comment: Try with adding this line: export default renderField; . Add this after declaring your const renderField.

Comment: where i will have to put this line?

Comment: Put it after declaring the const renderField.

Comment: still having the same error.I already export the register component using 'default'.is it possible to use 'default' in multiple times?

Comment: tried with export renderField but same error...

Comment: yes you can write multiple export. What version of react native you are using ?